# How do I have a function that multiplies 2 functions in r?

Tags: r, algebra, calculus

```
w         <- -1
pqxf      <- function(y)(1)*(y) # replace p with price of y
pqyf      <- function(x)(w*x)-(w*16) # -1.25 is the wage rate
utilityf  <- function(x)(80)*(1/(x)) # the utility function C,l
hours     <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to multiply pqxf and pqyf, to make utilityf

Comment: What are the inputs to these functions? Are `x` and `y` two different vectors of values? Or is `y` just a transformation of `x`?

Comment: 1) `(1)*(y) == y`. 2) Doesn't `utilityf` need an argument `y`? 3) I don't see a relation between the code comments and the code itself: there's no `p`, there's no `-1.25`.

Comment: yes, sorry the comments were when things were going well, it would be more helpful.  Also, p is w, I was going to make this into a wage/leisure calculator, and a general calculator, to compare the utility of differently priced goods (this is why pqy has a 1 in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to work out what `utilityf` should look like here, so let's use a simpler example. We have two functions `square()` and `inverse()`, and we want to do a calculation that involves squaring one set of numbers `a`, and multiplying by the inverse of another set of numbers `b`. First let's create the square and inverse functions:

```r
square <- function(a) {
    a^2
}

inverse <- function(b) {
    1 / b
}
```

These are just functions, they won't do anything until we **call** them and pass them an input.

Here's what you tried to do in a previous version of this question:

```r
output_bad <- function(a, b) {
    square * inverse
}
```

This doesn't work because we don't call the square and inverse functions at all, we don't give them inputs. So we end up trying to multiply one `function` object by another `function` object.

Here's the right way to do it:

```r
output <- function(a, b) {
    square(a) * inverse(b)
}
```

We provide `a` and `b` as inputs to our `output` function, and call square and inverse on them to get the individual results from those functions, which we can then multiply together. Now we can pass different values of `a` and `b` to `output`:

```r
> output(c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6))
# [1] 0.25 0.80 1.50
```

Comment: Ok, I got all that working, but now it won't change the slope or the value of utlilityf, when I change the value of w

Comment: I'm also getting an error message, saying that it doesn't recognize square as a function. Is there a library I need to open?

Comment: @user801855: you might want to make `w` an input to `utilityf`, i.e. `utilityf <- function(x, y, w)`, so that you can explicitly change it. The rules of how functions make use of global variables are a bit tricky, which is why it's often good to make things arguments when you need to be able to change them.

Comment: I thought I had w as a constant. I'm also not sure why the slope of pqxf doesn't change, when I assign different values to w.

Comment: @user801855 Yes, that is why I am suggesting you change `utilityf` so that `w` is an argument, not a value that's inherited from the global environment. That way you can generate results with multiple values for `w`.

Comment: `w         <- -1.25`
`pqxf      <- function(y)(1)*(y) # replace 1 with py and assign a value to py`
`pqyf      <- function(x)((w)*x)+((w)*16) # -1.25 is the wage rate`
`utilityf  <- function(x, y,w) { pqxf(x) * pqyf(y)*(1/w)} # the utility` `function C,l`
`utilityf(c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,20))`

Comment: Not sure I have this edited right (also sorry for the formatting, I think I need to use HTML to have everything on a separate line).